# Firebase performance always collecting data on Flutter when monitoring Custom URL

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-performance

I am using Firebase Performance Monitoring for my Flutter app. I am using this package

- dio: ^4.0.6
- firebase_core: ^1.20.0
- firebase_performance: ^0.8.2+1

I want to monitor the performance of network request custom URL for specific endpoints used in my app like this

[image]

It has been more than 24 hours already, but it is still collecting data, no data appears on the dashboard like the image above. what went wrong in here?

I believe I have put the correct URL, for example, my real URL is like this

> https://api.myCompany.id/api/blueray/customer/profile

so I put specific custom URL in the firebase performance dashboard like this

> api.myCompany.id/api/blueray/customer/profile

if I change the filter to 'All Network Request' like the image below, there is no record from our own backend/endpoint, it seems it only records the requests for some Google services.

[image]

am I missing something? I expect the data will automatically be collected by just installing that package above. do I need write some codes to populate the dashboard with data? or do I need to add native code?

I just add that package to my pubspec.yaml and run `pub get`, thats it

Comment: If you are using `dio` then you can try this plugin [dio_firebase_performance](https://pub.dev/packages/dio_firebase_performance)

Comment: @Sp4Rx unfortunately that package is no longer updated, no longer suitable with the latest firebase packages

Comment: check the pull requests of that package.

meanwhile you can try this https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_performance_dio

Comment: @Sp4Rx it works, thanks. it seems if we use Dio we have to add that interceptor based on this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/custom-network-traces?platform=flutter